# Как пишется сочетание «просто (не) нужный»?

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

***Всё вокруг – просто ненужная пыль, а тебе это нравится.***

Это предложение с другого форума, и ответы там были разные, например:

(1) Здесь раздельно, потому что есть дополнение ПРОСТО, плюс тире.
(2) В вашем случае слитно, т. к. можно подобрать синоним без «не»: ненужная = бесполезная, бессмысленная.

Меня же интересуют ваше мнение по таким вопросам:

(1) **Какой частью речи** является здесь слово «просто» (наречие, частица) и каково его **точное значение**?

(2) По правилу Розенталя на написание НЕ оказывают влияние **усилительные слова** (пункт 6):  Если в качестве пояснительного слова выступает наречие меры и степени (весьма, крайне, очень, почти или наречное выражение в высшей степени и т. п.), то частица НЕ с прилагательным всегда пишется слитно. http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77

Но можно ли отнести сюда слово «просто» и **считать его наречием меры и степени**? Тогда  НЕ будет  писаться только слитно.  И вообще говоря, почему такие наречия задают слитное написание? Вспомним, что при наличии слов «вовсе» и «совсем»  написание НЕ может быть как слитным, так и раздельным:  *вовсе не убедительные доводы, вовсе неизвестные авторы.*

(3) Можно ли определить  написание НЕ  для конкретного предложения **по его структуре и поставленным знакам?** Изменится ли форма письма при отсутствии слова «просто»:  Всё вокруг  –  ненужная пыль, а тебе это нравится.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Это точно частица, исходя из следующего пункта словаря:
просто *частица; разг.*
2) Всего лишь, всего-навсего; не иначе как. || Вот и его точное значение.
*Вы просто смеётесь над нами.

**Всё это просто детское упрямство.**

Он просто не умён.

Зашёл к вам просто так. (без особых причин, целей, намерений)

Зовите меня просто Ваней.

Учусь в Технологическом институте или просто в Техноложке.*

Непохоже на меру и степень. Похоже на слово, **указывающее на цельное качество** (слитное написание), как и три варианта замены из словаря.

> Изменится ли форма письма при отсутствии слова «просто»: Всё вокруг – ненужная пыль, а тебе это нравится.

Раздельное написание хотя бы станет допустимым, но останется неуместным.

> Можно ли определить написание НЕ для конкретного предложения по его структуре

Структура влияет, в самом конце больше всего шансов для раздельного написания.

Answer (score 0):

**Комментарий к ответу oleedd**

1. Да, п**охоже на частицу** со значением  «в прямом смысле, не иначе как».  Но можем ли мы включить «просто» в правило Розенталя и писать «просто ненужный» **всегда слитно**? Очень хотелось бы, тогда задача значительно упрощается, так как структуру предложения уже необязательно учитывать.
2. Но тогда  возникает  такой вопрос: может быть, **любое слово** с признаковым значением задает нам слитное написание? (Собственно говоря, только «вовсе не», «совсем не» могут писаться раздельно.)  Ведь наличие  собственных пояснительных слов (у прилагательных!) предполагает, что мы говорим **о словарном значении** слова «ненужный», а из этого следует **слитное письмо**. (Это не относится к отглагольным прилагательным, которые при наличии зависимых слов переходят в причастие: некошеный луг – давно не кошенный луг).
3. А вот **структура предложения**  задает как раз слитное, а не раздельное написание НЕ, если судить по логическим ударениям. (Здесь у нас разное мнение.)
   ***Всё вокрУг – просто ненужная пЫль, а тебе это нрАвится.*** Слово «ненужная» ударением не выделишь, а это требуется для раздельного написания. Аналогично:
   *Всё вокрУг – ненужная пЫль, а тебе это нрАвится.*
4. Ну и смотрим на ответы, данные на форуме: все неверно, или написание, или объяснение (а ведь отвечали «гении», «просветленные и т.д.).

Comment: *может быть, любое слово с признаковым значением задает нам слитное написание?* — это да. Вернее, то, которое указывает на признак. Можно сказать, что в таких случаях слитное написание будет лучше, но говорить, что во всех таких случаях раздельное написание будет ошибкой, очень рискованно. Вы заметили, что Розенталь часто употреблял "как правило", потому что не хотел рисковать? И далеко не всегда у него указано, когда происходит наоборот. А нам тем более не стоит так обобщать. Для этого нужны серьёзные научные исследования.

Comment: Формально мы не имеем право обобщать, это не будет доказательством, но для себя можно сделать заметку и заодно понаблюдать за правильностью вывода на примерах.  Я что-то пока таких примеров не знаю (с усилением отрицания для качественных прилагательных, кроме общеизвестных частиц).